# Show hidden object with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, show, hidden

We have a hidden ribbon and I'd like to change `.hidden` css in order for it to be displayed. My jquery doesn't seem to solve it?

**Html**

```
<div id="alwaysInStockRibbon" class="ribbon-wrapper-productpage hidden">
Css
```

**Css**

```
.hidden {
    display: none!important;
    visibility: hidden!important;
```

**My jQuery** do not work.

```
$(".hidden").css({"display":"Block","visibility":"visible"});
```

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example? Typically using `!important` is not a good thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove your hidden class :

```js
$(".hidden").removeClass("hidden");
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none!important;
    visibility: hidden!important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="alwaysInStockRibbon" class="ribbon-wrapper-productpage hidden">
  aaaaaaaaaa
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use show to make display back, but you will need to edit visibility too (also delete important from css):

```js
$(".hidden").show().css("visibility","visible");
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="alwaysInStockRibbon" class="ribbon-wrapper-productpage hidden">Hello world!</div>
```